# Video Skype on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, skype

Is there any way to use Skype with video on Arch?  The AUR package
doesn't install, and it seems that the web interface has no video.

Comment: from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/skype#Skype_for_Linux_Alpha , have you tried https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/skypeforlinux/ or https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/skypeforlinux-bin/?

Comment: @AndreiR, I tried a different one.  What's the difference between these, bin is precompiled?

Comment: @AndreiR, it says sorry, video support is not yet available for this platform.

Comment: Not an answer, but unless you **need** to use Skype, there are great Open Source alternatives, such as: https://jitsi.org/Projects/JitsiMeet

Comment: @maulinglawns, thanks, I'd absolutely prefer an alternative, but I also need to be able to use skype, sadly.

Comment: Not in arch, but in Ubuntu, I hardly make it work in text mode.